# Connecting Multiple Raspberry Pi to One Laptop

Tags: python, ssh, camera, ethernet

I'm trying to use my laptop to instruct multiple raspberry pi's to take a picture simultaneously.

I have a DHCP LAN network which connects to my laptop and raspberry pi through ethernet cables. I've assigned a static IP to my laptop (192.168.0.1) and to my raspberry pis (192.168.0.2) and (192.168.0.3)

How can I get my Raspberry Pi's to immediately execute a "listening" Python script upon startups waiting for prompts from my laptop to take these pictures? What script can I use from my laptop to instruct these pi's to take a picture?

Not sure if this would come in handy but my Pis are installed with Raspbian and my laptop with Windows 10.

Comment: so, are you asking, how do you start a python program on boot?

Comment: You have DHCP but use static addresses? Then DHCP seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the easiest way to trigger an event on 3 Pis at the same time](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73963/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-trigger-an-event-on-3-pis-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood the meaning of DHCP. I'm using a LAN device where I connect all computers to it through ethernet cables. Currently accessing the raspberry pi's through SSH. 

Yes. How do I start a python program on boot? Do you guys by chance know how to code a python script that accepts manual input from an external device?

Answer (score 1):

How simultaneously do you need it to be? If "within a couple of seconds" is fine, then just call your scripts sequentially via SSH:

```
sshpass -p 'raspberry' ssh pi@192.168.0.2 python take_photo.py &
sshpass -p 'raspberry' ssh pi@192.168.0.3 python take_photo.py &
```

You may want to setup a [passwordless login](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) to make the commands simpler.

If you need to be even faster (hundreds of milliseconds), you can keep the SSH sessions open and send commands to such open sessions:

```
#log in via SSH (using sshpass or manually)
sshpass -p 'raspberry' ssh pi@192.168.0.2 &
sshpass -p 'raspberry' ssh pi@192.168.0.3 &

# take note which PTS files got created

#later on from a script
echo python take_photo.py > /dev/pts/1
echo python take_photo.py > /dev/pts/2
```

For an even faster response, ditch the network entirely and wire a trigger signal to the GPIO. Any "python script that accepts manual input from an external device" you'll write will likely be just as slow as SSH is.